# Generating client libraries using endpoints.sh does not generate libs JAR

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, google-cloud-endpoints

Generating client libraries using endpoints.sh does not generate libs JAR.

I only get a generated `XXX..api-v1-java-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar` but no libs Jar with classfiles.

I want to use the endpoint libs in an android project, if i try to use the `*Api.Builder.java` through the "Link Source" functionality in eclipse, the project compiles correctly but on launch i get an `ClassDefNotFoundError`.

```
12-02 21:00:56.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13547): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.appspot.Api$Builder
```

My setup is eclipse Luna (4.4.1) with the App Engine SDK, Android Development Tools etc.

Comment: Can you provide the command you're using the generate the client lib? And possibly a screenshot or "tree" output of your project folder structure?

Comment: Was this solved for you? Are you still there?

Comment: I used the Eclipse Google Plugin to generate source. The solution was to exclude the Android Private Libraries and Dependencies from Build Path -> Export and Import

Comment: Thanks for coming back to provide the answer for other users who might have the same issue. Great SO etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to exclude the Android Private Libraries and Dependencies from Build Path. I don't know why, but eclipse always checks them after restart.

[image: android project build path settings]